# Eclipse - Open Resource - How to see only *.js files

Tags: eclipse

I need to see all javascript files in my application, so I tried Ctrl + Shift + R, and wrote *.js but it showing lot of other files like *.jsp.....But I have to see only *.js files.

Have any idea how to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a '<' to the end of the string, so:

```
*.js<
```

This is mentioned in the full dialog help, but not in the prompt line at the top of the dialog.

Comment: Magic, `*.js<` worked well first time, but not working now. I opened Open Resource popup(Ctrl + Shift + R) and I wrote `*.js<`.  Is it works only once per a day :). just kidding.